# Laravel 8: Get the class names of all Models that "morphOne" class of a specific relation

Tags: laravel, polymorphism, relationship, one-to-many, one-to-one

I need a list of the class names of all models that have an OneToOne or OneToMany polymorphic relationship definition to another specific model. This list must not be based on the actually existing relations in the corresponding database table but on the code definition.

**Example**

Class A, B, and C have a polymorphic one-to-one or one-to-many relation to Class X (the *able class).

I am searching for (an existing?) method to retrieve the class names of A, B, and C (or any other class with the same relation to X).

Answer (score 0):

The inverse of a `MorphOne` relation, is the `MorphTo` relation. However, with Eloquent, this relation does not have a definition of all the models that have a `MorphOne` relationship to itself.

###### Solution A

One simple solution would be to just record a static array on the `X` class which holds all possible classes for that relation, like so.

```php
class X extends Model
{
    public static array RELATION_OPTIONS = [
        App\A::class,
        App\B::class,
        App\C::class,
    ];

    public function foo(): MorphTo
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

The downside of this solution is that you will have to keep the array of model options in sync with the actual implementation of the inverse relationship. So whenever you add another model with a `MorphOne` relationship to `X`, you need to add it to the `RELATION_OPTIONS` array.

###### Solution B

Another solution would make use of looping over all `Models` to determine which of them have a relationship to `X`. In pseudocode that would mean you will have to something like this:

```php
$models = get_all_models(); // \Illuminate\Support\Collection
$models->filter(function (Model $model) {
    if ( ! method_exists($model, 'foo')) return false;

    $relation = $model->foo();

    if ( ! $relation instanceof MorphOne) return false;

    return $relation->getParent() instanceof X;
});
```

It's a less simple but more accurate solution that will always be in sync with the actual implementation. Take care though, you will want to *cache* the execution of this method as finding all models in an application (by looping over the filesystem) can be an expensive task.

Comment: Hi erikgaal, thanks a lot for your explanations. Solution A is what i am doing right now. Solution B is that type of solution i was searching for. Is it possible to somehow use Laravels caching-capabilities for caching? Or do i have to implement something on my own.

Comment: If you abstract this logic to some method, you could either "cache" it by using a static property on the model and making sure you only set it once (at boot, or when the property is needed). This way it runs only once per request. Another way would be to use Laravel's Cache system, but that would make it again more complicated.